# How to get UIViewController in a singleton?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm using a singleton class to validate a network response. Inside the function (`validResponse()`) I'm calling in the singleton, I call another function which pops up an alert box, to let the user know there was an error.

The function inside my singleton class:

```
func validResponse(data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?, viewController: UIViewController, context: String?) -> Bool {
    ...
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
            AlertHelper.showAlertWrapper(viewController: viewController, alertTitle: "Error", alertMessage: self.genericError)
        }
}
```

The `AlertHelper` code:

```
class AlertHelper {
    static func showAlertWrapper(viewController: UIViewController, alertTitle: String, alertMessage: String) {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: alertTitle, message: alertMessage, preferredStyle: .alert);

        let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil);
        alertController.addAction(okAction);

        viewController.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil);
    }
}
```

Calling `validResponse()`:

```
let result = self.networkHelper.validResponse(data: data, response: response, error: error, viewController: self, context: "Delete section")
```

In the above instance `self` is not going to work, and is just temporarily there until I figure out what to do. I understand I could just pass the relevant `UIViewController` in `viewController`, like I did for `showAlertWrapper`. However this is a bit messy.

Is there some way I can reference the currently present view controller in my singleton class, so that I dont have to pass it in `validResponse()`?

Comment: I would suggest that it is not your network helper's job to display the alert;  It should simply return the error via the completion handler and let that class display the alert if appropriate.

Comment: @Paulw11 ah, good point. I'll rework my helper class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to get the top most view controller currently showing in your app. You can do this by retrieving the top most view controller when your singleton wants to display an error.

```
class AlertHelper {
    static func showAlertWrapper(alertTitle: String, alertMessage: String) {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: alertTitle, message: alertMessage, preferredStyle: .alert);

        let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil);
        alertController.addAction(okAction);

        if var topController = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController {
            while let presentedViewController = topController.presentedViewController {
                topController = presentedViewController
            }

            // viewController should now be your topmost view controller
            viewController.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil);
        }
    }
}
```

And call your showAlertWrapper:

```
AlertHelper.showAlertWrapper(alertTitle: "Error", alertMessage: self.genericError)
```

Answer (score 1):

A workaround and maybe swiftier way would be to have the `showAlertWrapper`in the UIViewController:

```
extension UIViewController {
func showAlertWrapper(title: String, message: String) {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert);

        let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil);
        alertController.addAction(okAction);

       present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil);
    }
}
```

Then you would just do

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
            viewController.showAlertWrapper(title: "Error", message: self.genericError)
        }
```

Comment: Ah, I do like this way as well, and do agree, its probably the better way to go about it, so I've up voted you as well. Thanks.